# Facebook SDK cannot build SDK package because PlayServiceResolver not found

Tags: android, facebook, unity-game-engine

I have launched a game for a year and using Facebook login function for a long time. The login function worked properly but suddenly Facebook told me that the Facebook login function does not work so they froze it. I have no idea how to fix it so I tried to set up Facebook SDK again. However, when I try to build SDK Package for Android in Facebook setting menu, error comes out and saying that it cannot find PlayServiceResolver.

[image]

Play Services Resolver seems to be upgraded into External Dependency Manager and thus it can't find the path. How could I do to make Facebook SDK build the package? As I am also using Firebase and Firebase is using External Dependency Manager, I am looking for a solution rather than remove External Dependency Manager and install Play Services Resolver again.

Comment: I have the same problem. Does someone have a solution or info related to this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading to the newest Facebook SDK Version 16.0 fixes this issue.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).